# Tag Size and Cache Bits Exercise

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I am studying for my computer architecture exam that is due tomorrow and am stuck on a practice exercise regarding tag size and the total number of cache bits. Here is the question:

```
Question 8:
This question deals with main and cache memory only.
Address size: 32 bits
Block size: 128 items
Item size: 8 bits
Cache Layout: 6 way set associative
Cache Size: 192 KB (data only)
Write Policy: Write Back

Answer: The tag size is 17 bits. The total number of cache bits is 1602048.
```

I know that this a failry straight-forward exercise, but I seem to be lacking the proper formulas. I also know that the structure of a N set way associative is |TAG 25 bits|SET 2 bits|OFFSET 5 bits|. And that Tag size = AddrSize - Set - Offset (- item size if any) thus giving the answer of 17 bits tag size.

However, how do I calculate the total number of cache bits please?

Answer (score 0):

- cache size in bytes: 192*1024 = 196608
- number of blocks: 196608 / 128 = 1536
- number of sets: 1536 / 6 = 256
- set number bits: log2(256) = 8
- offset number bits: log2(128) = 7
- tag size: 32-(8+7) = 17
- metadata: valid+dirty = 2 bits
- total tag + metadata: (17+2)*1536 = 29184 bits
- total data: 1536*128*8 = 1572864 bits
- total size: 29184 + 1572864 = 1,602,048

There could also be bits used for the replacement policy, but we can assume it's random to make the answer work.